Transferring Assets Between Ethereum and Binance Smart Chain
i would like to know how to Transfer crypto Assets Between Ethereum and Binance Smart Chain . Many thanks

The easiest way is to have an account at Binance exchange and use it as a centralised bridge.

In order to transfer assets between different chains, you need to use a bridge. The simplest way is to use Metamask's built in bridge function: https://portfolio.metamask.io/bridge?metametricsId=null.
Here you can find a list of bridges used on the Ethereum network:
https://www.alchemy.com/list-of/web3-bridges-on-ethereum.

gas fees are very high ,  is there a programaticly way .

You've got to broadcast a transaction to the blockchain and pay a gas fee no matter what.
